# Create Multidimensional Tree Object From Array In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to take an array that turns the key (split by `/`) of each element into a child array, and assigns the data in the right format in the new array.
There can be multiple levels of nesting, realistically never more then 10, but that is to be decided.

For example; 
given the input of

```
$i_have_this = [
    "Base/child" => [
      [
        "filename" => "child-1",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ],
      [
        "filename" => "child-2",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ],
      [
        "filename" => "child-3",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ]
    ],
    "Base/child/grandChild1" => [
      [
        "filename" => "grandChild1-1",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ]
    ],
    "Base/child/grandChild2" => [
      [
        "filename" => "grandChild2-1",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ],
      [
        "filename" => "grandChild2-2",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ],
      [
        "filename" => "grandChild2-3",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ],
      [
        "filename" => "grandChild2-4",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ],
      [
        "filename" => "grandChild2-5",
        "last_modified" => "29/01/2020"
      ]
    ]
];
```

I would like the output of

```
$want_this = [
    'name' => 'Base',
    'children' => [
        [
            'name' => 'child',
            'children' => [
                ["name" => "child-1"],
                ["name" => "child-2"],
                ["name" => "child-3"],
                [
                    "name" => "grandChild1",
                    "children" => [
                        ["name" => "grandChild1-1"]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "grandChild2",
                    "children" => [
                        ["name" => "grandChild2-1"],
                        ["name" => "grandChild2-2"],
                        ["name" => "grandChild2-3"],
                        ["name" => "grandChild2-4"]
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

So far I have;

```
foreach($i_have_this as $path => $value) {
    $temp = &$want_this;

    foreach (explode('/', $path) as $key) {
        $temp = &$temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = $value;

}
```

but can't quite finish it off.

[Example code run here](https://3v4l.org/gM0vA)

Comment: You will have a problem because in PHP you are not allowed to repeat keys. Instead you would have to number them name1, name2 etc or have a different structure. Could you update your question?

Comment: no keys are repeated, they are all in their own array

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer but maybe think about using a recursive function that calls itself.  Its helpful when you don't know exactly how many levels you're going to need.  Not sure if that will exactly help you but might point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could treat this the same way that most use "dot" notation for arrays (like in Laravel). Just replace "." with "/" in your case:

[Example Code](https://3v4l.org/n97Bd)

```
function unflatten($data) {
  $output = [];
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $parts = explode('/', $key);
    $nested = &$output;
    while (count($parts) > 1) {
      $nested = &$nested[array_shift($parts)];
      if (!is_array($nested)) $nested = [];
    }
    $nested[array_shift($parts)] = $value;
  }
  return $output;
}

print_r(unflatten($i_have_this));
```